# How can i evaluate SpaCy retrained model's accuracy?

Tags: model, spacy, evaluate

I have re-trained my SpaCy model. How should I evaluate the retrained model's accuracy?

Comment: Please post what you tried

Comment: What kind of model do you have? The evaluation metrics depend on what type of model (NER, classification, etc).